# Не работает php код через ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Обычный поиск файлов, работает.

```
  $j=0;

  if ($handle = opendir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/'.$_GET['project'])) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
     $fullname=getExtension($file);
      if ($fullname[1] == 'php') {
       $filenameX[$j]=$fullname[0];
      $j++;
    }
  }
}
closedir($handle);
```

}

Но если делаю аяксом, то есть этот скрипт является обработчиком ajax запроса - выдает ошибку 500.
почему?
других ошибок нет, проверял по строчкам. ошибка 500 повляется из за цикла

```
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
```

пути все верные. без аякса все работает.

Comment: Я все же спрошу, нельзя ли показать код отправки ajax запроса?

Comment: esli vi pravilno ukazali cherez ajax http put k php file u i otpravili pravilniy get parametr,to ya dumayu chto vse budet rabotat.Poprobuyte skopirovat url posle testirovki cherez brauser(GT zapros), i peredat v ajax tak kak on viglyadit.sli vse rabotaet to smotrite chto vi nedoperedali

Comment: Можете добавить что находится  в apache/php-fpm логе после ajax запроса, а также что приходит в теле ответа?

Comment: банальные ошибки исключены. аякс работает, приходит ответ.
но именно эта часть скрипта выдает ошибку 500.
и путь читает, глобальные переменные видит. как будто не может сканить папки! почему?
аналогичные скрипты у меня работают. а с этим запара какая то!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

допер сам, дело было в функции.
почему то из под функций нельзя вызывать другие функции.

кусок кода:

```
$fullname=getExtension($file);
```

заменил на:

```
$fullname=explode(".", $file);
```

и ошибка пропала. 
кто подскажет почему так?(